# Custom view for Drag and Drop

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have set up my `UITableView` to use the new Drag and Drop APIs.

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    self.tableView.dragDelegate = self
    self.tableView.dropDelegate = self
    self.tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

Now, I implemented the method below to be able to use custom views for the d&d.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, previewForLifting item: UIDragItem, session: UIDragSession) -> UITargetedDragPreview? {
    print("Custom Preview method called!")
    let test = UITextView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    test.text = "sfgshshsfhshshfshsfh"
    let dragView = interaction.view!
    let dragPoint = session.location(in: dragView)
    let target = UIDragPreviewTarget(container: dragView, center: dragPoint)
    return UITargetedDragPreview(view: test, parameters:UIDragPreviewParameters(), target:target)
}
```

However, this method never gets called. I never see the `print()` or my custom view. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You have to set `previewProvider` property when creating the UIDragItem.

```
let dragItem = UIDragItem(...)
dragItem.previewProvider = {
    print("Custom Preview method called!")
    let test = UITextView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    test.text = "sfgshshsfhshshfshsfh"
    return UIDragPreview(view: test)
}
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidragitem/2890972-previewprovider?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an iPhone? I am not certain it is currently working for customer `UIViewController` as of November 25, 2017 based on the following:

- I downloaded the Apple [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_custom_view) for drag-and-drop on an iPad
- I added a breakpoint in `dragInteraction` and confirmed I could reach it
- I modified the target to be a universal app (i.e. iPhone, too)
- I ran on an iPhone 8 device and did *not* reach the breakpoint

As further suggestion, there is a property named `dragInteractionEnabled` for both `UITableViewController` and `UICollectionViewController`. For iPhone devices, the property is defaulted to `false` and, more importantly, the property is not even defined higher in `UIViewController`.

Comment: on your view you should set `.dragInteractionEnabled = true` and on your `UIDragInteraction` object set the `.isEnabled = true`