# SwiftUI | onDrag - customize (dragItem) preview image appearance

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been wondering if there is any way to customize the `preview image` of the `view` that's being dragged when using `onDrag`?

[image]

As you might see, the `preview image` is by default a slightly bigger opacity image of the view.

From what I have found, a `preview image` is generated at the very beginning of the dragging process. But I couldn't find a way to change it.

What I mean by customizing is to have some custom `image` or a `preview image` of a custom `view`. (Both without the default opacity)

Does anyone have an idea?

I have tried to use [previewImageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemprovider/1403904-previewimagehandler) and in general, read a lot about the `NSItemProvider`. But for me, it seems like this is something that is not possible for SwiftUI yet?

With `UIKit` one could have just customized the `UIDragItem` - something like that using `previewProvider`: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140854/custom-view-for-drag-and-drop)

Here is my demo code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        DraggedView()
            .onDrag({ NSItemProvider() })
    }
    
    
    private struct DraggedView: View {
    
        var body: some View {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .frame(width: 120, height: 160)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
    }
}
```

I will use this for drag and drop within a `LazyVGrid`, so custom `gestures` are unfortunately no option.

One second idea I had would be to have a gesture simultaneously that first changes the `item` to be dragged to something else and then `onDrag` starts and returns the `NSItemProvider` with the `preview image` which would be then the one I would want. But I couldn't have those two gestures go at the same time, you would have to dismiss one first in order to start the second.

Thank you!

Comment: It is explicitly documented: "Applying the `onDrag(_:)` modifier adds the appropriate gestures for drag and drop to this view. **When a drag operation begins, a rendering of
this view is generated and used as the preview image**."

Comment: So there is no way to customize this? Or any workarounds?

Comment: Why not? From scratch, starting at low level from LongPressGesture & DragGesture, and everything else manually... long way, but possible.

Comment: I have tried this and failed, this is too much for me since there are so many things to consider with and I don't think this would be as good as apples onDrag, onDrop.

Comment: From my very long search. There is no way to control the preview image that is generated for the `onDrag(_:)` modifier. I'm more interested in getting a reference for the preview so I can save it as an image, but I got stuck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

iOS 15 adds an API to do this - you can specify the `View` to use for the `preview`. [onDrag(_:preview:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/ondrag(_:preview:))

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
    .frame(width: 120, height: 160)
    .foregroundColor(.green)
    .onDrag {
        NSItemProvider()
    } preview: {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 140)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
    }
```