# How to remove the background of list items when dragging (and when long-pressing) with onMove in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I have a list in SwiftUI like so:

```
@State var items = ["item0", "item1", "item2"]
List {
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 65)
            Text(item)
        }                            
        .onMove { from, to in
            items.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
        }
    }
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)      
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

The idea is to display items in the ForEach as if they are just "floating" on the screen, rather than in a list.

[image]

However, when I'm dragging a list item (to reorder it in the list; from the .onMove() modifier), a white background appears:

[image]

I would like to remove this background, so it looks like I'm just moving the list items (just the rounded rectangles, no background). How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I have added `.onDrag {} \@ViewBuilder preview: {}` which removes the background while actively dragging, but it still appears when we long-hold the item, right before we start dragging.

Comment: If there's a way to explicitly modify the preview that is shown when dragged, I'd also like to change the opacity.

Comment: This question seems like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64316054/swiftui-ondrag-customize-dragitem-preview-image-appearance).

Comment: @burnsi that question uses onDrag, which allows for a preview closure, whereas I am using onMove

Comment: @burnsi is right. The link provided is in the essence the same question, is answered as not-possible or, after iOS 16, possible with .onDrag {} \@ViewBuilder preview: {}

Comment: You can specify a preview, but when you long-hold the list item (right before you start dragging), the list item background will still appear.

Answer (score 0):

The white background appears, because of the default cell selection type in the `List`, which unfortunately can't be modified as of now.

Workaround for this would be to use `ScrollView` and `LazyVStack` combination and implement the **reordering logic manually**.

Something like this

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

/// This represents a simple item in your list
struct ListItem: View {
    let item: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 65)
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}

/// We need custom NSItemProvider to track when the drop finishes
final class ListItemProvider: NSItemProvider {
    var onCompletion: (() -> ())?

    deinit {
       onCompletion?()
    }
}

/// ViewModel to handle the state changes
/// You can emit this and simply use @State objects in your view
/// as you have done in your example
final class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var items = ["item0", "item1", "item2"]
    @Published private(set) var draggedItem: String?

    func shouldHighlight(item: String) -> Bool {
        return draggedItem == item
    }

    func move(to item: String) {
        guard let draggedItem,
              let from = items.firstIndex(of: draggedItem),
              let to = items.firstIndex(of: item),
              item != draggedItem else { return }

        items.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from), toOffset: to > from ? to + 1 : to)
    }

    func startInteraction(item: String) -> NSItemProvider {
        let provider = ListItemProvider(item: nil, typeIdentifier: item)
        provider.onCompletion = { [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.draggedItem = nil
            }
        }
        
        if draggedItem == nil && items.contains(item) {
            draggedItem = item
        }

        return provider
    }
}

/// Custom drop delegate to implement custom reordering logic
struct ListDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let item: String
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ListViewModel

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        viewModel.shouldHighlight(item: item)
    }

    func dropUpdated(info: DropInfo) -> DropProposal? {
        .init(operation: .move)
    }

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        withAnimation(.default) {
            self.viewModel.move(to: self.item)
        }
    }
}

/// And finally the view
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ListViewModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.self) { item in
                    ListItem(item: item)
                        .opacity(viewModel.shouldHighlight(item: item) ? 0 : 1)
                        .onDrag { viewModel.startInteraction(item: item) }
                        .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: ListDropDelegate(item: item, viewModel: viewModel))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

An alternative way: Use sections (this may be the cause of the background while reordering)

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
            Section {
                Text(item)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
            }
            .listSectionSeparator(.automatic)
            .listSectionSeparatorTint(.clear)
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
        .onMove(perform: move)
    }
    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
}


func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    items.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
}
```

- Don't need a ZStack, config Text
- Needs work with animation and edge cases, but no background wen reordering