How do you remove background artifacts fix the row disappearing when reordering items in a SwiftUI list?
When I attempt to move these rows I get a white background around each of my custom rows:

And when I attempt to drag to reorder the row in the List disappears:

Here's the code I'm using:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct PrioritizeAreas: View {
    @State private var categories: [CategoryItem] = [CategoryItem(category: "A", sortOrder: 0),
                                                     CategoryItem(category: "B", sortOrder: 1),
                                                     CategoryItem(category: "C", sortOrder: 2)]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.green, .indigo], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom).ignoresSafeArea()
            
            List {
                ForEach(categories) { item in
                    Text(item.category)
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        .frame(height: 42)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22)
                                .foregroundStyle(.orange.blendMode(.normal).opacity(1))
                        }
                }
                .onMove { indices, newOffset in
                    categories.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
                }
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 0, bottom: 4, trailing: 0))
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            }
            .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
    }
    
    private struct CategoryItem: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        let category: String
        let sortOrder: Int
    }
}

#Preview {
    NavigationStack {
        PrioritizeAreas()
    }
}

How do you remove these visual artifacts when reordering a SwiftUI list?
Note: The background is a linear gradient that I want to preserve.
This is on iOS 17.4 using Xcode Version 15.4 (15F31d)

There are many questions like this. None of the answers are great though. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76981128/5133585
